# Comparing the time to run the script

Tags: jmeter

The task is to compare the time to run the sampler. The sampler should run between 10:00 and 18:00. I try to use if controller, but it does not run scripts.

```
${__time(hh:mm)} > ${__timeShift(hh:mm,10:00,,,)}
```

I use this line in if controller. How best to implement this condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the below approach:-

1. Set a user defined variable as shown below:-

[image]
2. Then use the JSR223 Post Processor under a request to execute the below code.

```
def start_Time = vars.get("startTime")
log.info "start_Time>>>>>>>"+start_Time

long currentTime = ${__time(,)}
log.info "currentTime>>>>>>>"+currentTime;

long diff=currentTime.toLong()-start_Time.toLong();
log.info "diff>>>>>>>"+diff

if(diff>=2000){
    start_Time = ${__time(,)};
    vars.put("startTime",start_Time.toString());
}
vars.put("flag",diff.toString());
log.info "FlagValue>>>>>>>"+vars.get("flag")
```

[image]
3. Below is if condition used for the authentication request.

[image]

But, it is sending request after a specific time. Not, with in some duration randomly. You can use Random timer along with the request under the "If Controller" to send it at random interval. So, after certain time run the IF Contoller which will have your request and a random timer.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers